# Site doesn't work on localhost with the ".htaccess"

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp

I neet to put a CMS that i got, to work on localhost, the problem is that it is working only if i delete the .htaccess file. If the .htaccess is in the root folder the site doesn't work and when i delete the .htaccess file and the site is working i can't access the admin pannel using "http://localhost/putina/admin", I receive the error "The requested URL /putina/admin was not found on this server.". Here is my .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript

<filesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
</filesMatch>
```

Comment: Have you checked the access log to see where it points to?

Comment: I assume that the .htaccess is something you got from the CMS? If so, try downloading a new .htaccess from that CMS, it might've been a old / broken file.

Comment: the CMS is unique/custom made. Why I can't access the site (localhost) if this file .htaccess  is in root folder?

Comment: And this is my access log: " 127.0.0.1 - - [14/Aug/2015:09:28:23 +0300] "GET /putinasoacrei/ HTTP/1.1" 500 614 "

Comment: Is that the log message when you try to access http://localhost/putina/admin ?

Comment: When I try to access localhost/putina/ (the site). I can't access the site if i have the htaccess file in the folder.

Comment: try setting `RewriteBase` to `/putina/`

Comment: have you try to access the site using index.php in url? like http://localhost/putina/index.php/ <br>
http://localhost/putina/index.php/admin

Comment: no result if i use " RewriteBase  /putina/ " or if i tipe " http://localhost/putina/index.php " . Something is blocking my access to the site (the rewrite_module it is ON)

Comment: Any idea how to change this .htaccess file to make the CMS work on local PC? Mention: The CMS with this .htaccess file is working fine on ONLINE (on a hosting server)